# Direct Product and Direct sum of a Category (Integer divide)

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

> For the following category, give a definition of the direct product and direct sum; determine if they exist; if they do, give an explicit description, and give an explicit description of the direct product and the direct sum over an empty set:
>
> > The category $D \mathbb{Z}$.  In this category, the objects are the integers, and there are no morphisms from $m$ to $n$ unless $m$ divides $n$, in which case there is only one morphism.

$$Ob(D \mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{Z} $$

\begin{equation*}
\text{Mor}(m,n) = \begin{cases}
\{*_{m,n}\} & \text{if } \; m|n \\
\emptyset & \text{otherwise}. \\
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

Where we use the notation $m\mid n$ means $m$ divides $n$ if there exists $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ s.t. $mk=n$.

I think the category $D \mathbb{Z}$ is the set of ideals created by $d \in D$

E.g. $D=3$ then $D \mathbb{Z} = \{..., -6,-3,0,3,6, ...\}$

The direct product is the usual multiplication $(\times)$

$$if \; m|n \Rightarrow m|\lambda \times n, (\forall \lambda) $$

And direct is sum the usual addition $(+)$

$$if \; m|a \; and \; m|b \Rightarrow m|a+b$$

There is no direct product nor direct sum when we do not have an $m|n$ as there is no morphism.

When we do have $m|n$ then the direct product and direct sum over an empty set are vacuously empty.

Comment: Nope. There are morphisms from the direct product of $a,b$ to $a$ and to $b$. This means that the direct product has to divide both $a$ and $b$. $ab$ doesn't have this property, in general. Similarly, there are morphisms from $a$ and $b$ to the direct sum, so both $a$ and $b$ have to divide the direct sum. $a+b$ doesn't have this property, in general.

Comment: Good. Are you getting the idea now? The direct product & direct sum will be familiar. Don't forget the other property of each. E.g. for direct product, anything else that divides both $a$ and $b$ has to "factor through" the direct product in the sense that some diagram commutes.

Comment: Ah i want to reply but i have another class now, till later, and thank you(:

Comment: @BrianO I guess I don't understand.  I thought from your first comment that neither the direct product nor direct sum exist.  I know so little, is my example of $D \mathbb{Z}$ correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(Direct sum)** In the category $D\Bbb Z$, for $a,b\in \Bbb Z$, 
the direct sum is 
$$
a \coprod b := \operatorname{lcm}(a,b),
$$
the least common multiple of $a,b$ (which we'll take to be $\ge 0$).

Clearly, $a\!\mid\!\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)$ and $b\!\mid\!\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)$.
That is, there are morphisms
$$
a\longrightarrow \operatorname{lcm}(a,b) \longleftarrow b.
$$
Suppose now that $x$ is such that
$$
a\longrightarrow x \longleftarrow b,
$$
which means $a\!\mid\! x$ and $b \!\mid\! x$. Then by definition of "$\operatorname{lcm}$", we have $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)\!\mid\! x$, which is to say, there is a (necessarily unique) morphism
$$
\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)\longrightarrow x,
$$
such that

- the (unique) morphism $a\to x$ equals the composition of the morphisms $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)\to a\to x$, and
- the (unique) morphism $b\to x$ equals the composition of the morphisms $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)\to b\to x$.

These two bullet points are trivial: "divides" is transitive, and for any $y,z\in \Bbb Z$ there is at most one morphism $y\to z$.

**(Direct sum of the empty set)** 
$$
\coprod \emptyset = 0.\quad\text{(Why?)}
$$

**(Direct product, direct product of the empty set)** Exercise.

Comment: Wow thank you!  I pretty much understand this except for why $a \to x \gets b$ tells us $x|$ and $x|b$.. Doesn't this say if $a \to x$ then $\exists k \; s.t. \; ak=x$?  Which is defined as $a|x$ ... not $x|a$.  I see though if this is true then there is an arrow that is drawn from $lcm(a,b) \to x$ And the direct sum is the least common multiple because, it has to be divisible by both a and b; but why least?

Comment: You'll kick yourself, if that's even possible: because of the definition of the category, there is a morphism $a\to x \iff a\!\mid\! x$. This category is an example of a category representing a reflexive transitive order $\preceq$ a.k.a. a preorder (here, it's the "divides" relation); in such a category, there's a unique morphism $x\to y$ iff $x \preceq y$.

Comment: Okay I think I understand something, that the product and coproduct go in opposite directions.  Your first comment finally makes sense!  Then 

$$a \prod b := gcd(a,b)$$

I think though that the direct product of the empty set does not exist, as we can't divide by the empty-set nor by zero.  And the direct sum over the empty set is zero because $a*0=b$ holds true for any $a,b$ .. although I still don't really see why this is not $\coprod \emptyset = \emptyset$.  I'm sorry I'm so clueless!

Comment: Ooops/good catch: I wrote it backwards. :| Fixed.

Comment: Great!!! thank you, I understand that part now haha :D

Comment: Yes, the direct product is lcm :)

Comment: OK Now for direct product (coprod) of $\emptyset$, this would be something $x$ such that (1) everything in $\emptyset$ divides x [BUT this is true of every $x$ !! ], and (2) for any $y$ such that everything in $\emptyset$ divides $y$, $x|y$. That simplifies to: every $y$ divides $x$, i.e. for every $y$ there is $k$ such that $yk = x$. Then $x$ can only be $0$. // By similar reasoning, the direct product of the empty set is $1$.

Comment: Thank you thank @BrianO, you've been so very helpful!!! <3

Comment: You're welcome, thank you! Good luck.